# MVC 4 the button will be clicked after a specific period of time

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working with MVC 4 razor and I have a problem. I couldn't find anything in web the same as my problem. I don't know how do I code it.

Example: After clicking the first button at 6:00 am, the second button will automatically be clicked after 7:00 am or clicking the first button at 6:30 am, the second button will still automatically be clicked after 7:00 am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setTimeout` method to execute some javascript function after a certain period of time.

So basically when your first button is clicked, start a timer using setTimeout and programatically click the second button using the `trigger` jQuery method.

For example, the below code will programatically click the second button after 5 seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#button1").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('first button clicked');
        var delayDuration = 5000;  // 5 seconds
        var j = window.setTimeout(function() {
                 console.log("going to trigger click on button 2");
                 $("#button2").trigger( "click" );
            },
            delayDuration);

    });

    $("#button2").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('second button clicked');
    });

});
```

**Keep in mind that, this is client side javascript code. that means user need to have his browser/page open for that much time (1 hour/30 minutes or whatever the delay duration is) for it to work.**

If you are trying to do something automatic (Without the browser being open), you should use some sort of task scheduling mechanism in the server.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/movilivefu/edit?html,js,output) is a working jsbin